# how to break in middleware in expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack

I have a MEAN stack based web application and I have a middle ware which validates the request for some authorization purpose. I have written the security checking part but if the user is unauthorized, the express middle ware should stop execution and return back user 401 status with a message. How can I achieve it? I tried to to use return statement in middle ware but it is not working. Though some of them works, it throws an exception and breaks the server. I want just an abrupt ending to the request. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you have `response` object. Don't you?

Comment: Yes.I do.I have the object

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.end ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `isValid` is a hypothetical function to check the validity of the request.

```
function authMiddleware(req,res,next){
  if(isValid(req)){
   next(); // calls the next middleware
  }else {
   return res.sendStatus(401); // sends HTTP 401 back
  }
}
```

Comment: If there are more lines after res.status like below ; will it get executed
Mine is a bigger code with more than 100 lines ; if 10th line gives not valid , i dont want others to get executed...putting all in else ;gives me a lot of if else if else constructs

Comment: @Jocket You can just return on the line where you set res.status(401).send("...")

Comment: Its returning properly..But server fails with
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:356:11)

Comment: That would only happen if headers are being set on response (directly or indirectly by setting the status etc) after send or similar method is called (like res.status(200).json("good!") ) etc.

Comment: I tried exactly your code..It reaches the return statement then it fails

Comment: Try res.sendStatus(401)

Comment: Its the same..the server failing is the reason why i posted in SOF

Comment: You might have another middleware which already sets the header. Try disabling all other middleware and see if it works, then add them back one by one until you find the culprit

Comment: But since i am ending response by res.sendStatus ,will it call the other middlewares?